# GitLab: Not all committer names showing up in Graphs/Contributors

Tags: gitlab

I created a new GitLab project and migrated my existing code from SVN following the 
["Migrating from SVN to GitLab" instructions](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/importing/migrating_from_svn.html). All the project commits and contributors appear in the Commits view and elsewhere.

However, in the Graphs/Contributors commits are misattributed and some contributors don't appear at all. Is this somehow expected or is this an indication that the migration was not 100% successful?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was caused by not following well the format specification of the `authors.txt` file. The file should look like this:

```
janedoe = Jane Doe <janedoe@example.com>
johndoe = John Doe <johndoe@example.com>
```

but instead we did this

```
janedoe = (blank) <janedoe@example.com>
johndoe = (blank) <johndoe@example.com>
```

After reimporting the SVN repository it looks as expected and the names show up everywhere.